# Access struct member by name in Go template

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

I'm hoping to create a common/generic Go html template which will produce a standard html table based on its inputs. I had hoped to look up the struct members by name, but I haven't been able to make this work.

I've had a look around and I can't find a solution, so I'm either missing something obvious, or the approach is wrong. In this respect I would accept a solution which showed an alternate or better approach which avoids trying this lookup.

Example Template:

```
{{ $fields := .FieldMap }}
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    {{ range $key, $value := $fields }}
        <th>{{ $key }}</th>
    {{ end }}
    </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{ range $i, $v :=  .Model }}
    <tr>
        {{ $rowData := . }}
{{/* FAILS: error calling index: can't index item of type main.Person  <td> {{ index . "FirstName"}}</td>*/}}
        {{ range $key, $value := $fields }}

{{/* FAILS: error calling index: can't index item of type main.Person   <td> {{ index $rowData $value }}</td>*/}}
{{/* FAILS: bad character U+0024 '$'                                    <td> {{ $rowData.$value }}</td>*/}}
        {{ end }}
    </tr>
    {{ end }}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Example Go:

package main

```
import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

type Person struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName string
}

type Animal struct {
    Species string
}

type TemplateData struct {
    Model interface{}
    FieldMap map[string]string
}

func main() {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("table.gohtml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Here we use Person, but I may want to pass other types of struct to the template, for example "Animal"
    dataPerson := TemplateData{
        Model: []Person{
            {
                FirstName: "Test",
                LastName:  "Template",
            },
        },
        FieldMap: map[string]string{"First": "FirstName", "Last": "LastName"},
    }

    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, dataPerson)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I hope its clear what I am trying to do - have a single template which I can reuse across various types of struct.

Comment: You can't. If you want to iterate keys/values in a template, use a `map`, not a `struct`.

Comment: So would you recommend converting the struct to something like a map[string]interface - where the key is the member name?

Comment: That's really your choice to make. Personally it seems extremely unlikely to me that you'll end up with an application where you use the same template to render a bunch of different objects and just want to list all their fields in arbitrary order with no special formatting or behavior at all. That sounds like debugging, which I would probably just use JSON or something for. So, it seems like just using structs with different templates is the sane long-term solution. But it's your project, you know it better than anyone on SO will, it's your design decision to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a template function that returns the struct field names and values as a map:

```
// fields returns map of field names and values for struct s.
func fields(s interface{}) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(s))
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%T is not a struct", s)
    }
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    t := v.Type()
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        sv := t.Field(i)
        m[sv.Name] = v.Field(i).Interface()
    }
    return m, nil
}
```

Specify the function when parsing the file:

```
t, err := template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{"fields": fields}).ParseFiles("table.gohtml")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Use it like this:

```
{{range $i, $v :=  .Model}}
<tr>
    {{$m := fields $v}}
    {{range $key, $value := $fields}}
       <td>{{index $m $value}}</td>
    {{end}}
</tr>
{{end}}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bgBU33H65D2).

Another approach is to write a function that looks up a field by name:

```
func field(s interface{}, k string) (interface{}, error) {
    v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(s))
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%T is not a struct", s)
    }
    v = v.FieldByName(k)
    if !v.IsValid() {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("no field in %T with name %s", s, k)
    }
    return v.Interface(), nil
}
```

Parse with the function:

```
t, err := template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{"field": field}).ParseFiles("table.gohtml")
```

Use it like this:

```
{{range $i, $v :=  .Model}}
<tr>
    {{range $key, $value := $fields}}
       <td>{{field $v $value}}</td>
    {{end}}
</tr>
{{end}}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bgBU33H65D2).

Comment: Thanks - the second approach was what I needed. from within Go gin framework you can add template functions in at the router/engine 
 router := gin.Default()
 router.SetFuncMap(template.FuncMap{
  "field": field,
 })